# How to create a linked list by python in this class

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list

I see a linked list class definition in Leetcode:

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):          
        self.val = val
        self.next = None
```

I am confused how to use it, there are two methods I want to figure out:

Firstly:
if I want to create a linked list 1->3->5 step by step, how? My idea is that:

```
p1 = ListNode(1)
p2 = ListNode(3)
p3 = ListNode(5)

p2 = p1.next
p3 = p1.next.next
print(p1.val)  #however it shows p1 doesn't have next attr...
```

Secondly, if I have a linked list, like that:

```
l1 = ListNode([1, 2, 4, 6])
```

How to get every value step by step?
I tried like:

```
print(l3.next) 
print(l3.next.next)#maybe just some false idea...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor is wrong: it sets `self.next` to `None` rather than to `next`. Let’s fix that:

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next
```

Now we can create a list of three nodes. Since this is a singly-linked forward list, we need start at the back:

```
p3 = ListNode(3)
p2 = ListNode(2, p3)
p1 = ListNode(1, p2)

print(p1.next.next.val) # 3
```

Or, to generate a linked list from a list:

```
def from_list(lst) -> ListNode:
    node = None
    for item in lst[::-1]:
        node = ListNode(item, node)

    return node

x = from_list([1, 2, 3, 4])
print(x.next.next.next.val) # 4
```